# Call a generic method by by specifying only one of the two inputs

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface

```
public interface IHtmlConverter<TResponse> where TResponse : class
{
    Task<TResponse> Convert(IDocument document);
}
```

I have implemented that interface like this

```
public class ItemsConverter : IHtmlConverter<ItemsResponse>
{
    public Task<ItemsResponse> Convert(IDocument document)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I also created an extension to use the converters

```
public static class DocumentExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TResponse> Convert<TConverter, TResponse>(this IDocument document)
        where TConverter : IHtmlConverter<TResponse>, new()
        where TResponse : class
    {
        var htmlConverter = new TConverter();

        var result = await htmlConverter.Convert(document);

        return result;
    }
}
```

In order to use it, I need to call it like that

```
ItemsResponse response = await document.Convert<ItemsConverter, ItemsResponse>();
```

ItemsConverter specifies that it using ItemsResponse as the generic input, is there any way to make the extension work by just specifying the converter? Like this:

```
ItemsResponse response = await document.Convert<ItemsConverter>();
```

I remember seeing a library that managed to do it but I'm not sure which one it was to look at the source code.

Comment: I wouldn't think so because you would need to define the return type for `Task<TResponse>`. Since it would need to compile/run to know that, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @thalacker yes makes sense